# PIL python,License and Distribution

Tags: python, licensing, python-imaging-library

Good morning, I have created a little software for photo retouch by PIL python. By py2exe i have created an exe version from my .py file. In my dist and build folder I can find PIL module pyc and every file that permit at my program to work on every computer without python.Now i would distribute this program freeware (only .exe and not the source code) by a my web site. I read on PIL software license this

**Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software and its associated documentation for any purpose and without fee is hereby granted, provided that the above copyright notice appears in all copies, and that both that copyright notice and this permission notice appear in supporting documentation, and that the name of Secret Labs AB or the author not be used in advertising or publicity pertaining to distribution of the software without specific, written prior permission.**

If i have only .pyc file in my distr and build folder created by py2exe how can I maintain the copyright notice?

In a day, my web site will have many visit perhaps i will put ADsense Google to have little profit, are there any PIL license violation? About license, distribution I'm very confused...could someone help me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you put the notice in the documentation of your program, you're free to distribute your program.

Regarding the advertisement in the license, it concerns only the advertising of your own program. It means you're not allowed to use the name of Secret Labs AB on the download page of your program, or on an ad if you're buying ad space to distribute your program for example.

Comment: Hi,thank you very much for your answer and excellent explation about license and distribution ! Hi Paolo

Answer (score 0):

Adding to ssidorenko answer: If you really want to make sure to contain the copyright notice on your packaged executable, maybe add it as a "docstring" to the source code, and then it should be contained in the generated `*.pyc` as well. (I see `py2exe` can be configured at setup time to generate optimized `*.pyo` files - in that case, do not use the `-OO` when running `python setup.py py2exe`, as it will remove docstrings from the generated `*.pyo` file.) You can make clear in the docstring that this is the notice for PIL e.g. by saying "This software contains PIL with the following copyright notice:..."

Comment: Thank you very much! now i have a clear idea about what i must do for respect PIL license and distribute my software.Thanks again!Hi Paolo

Comment: If it works for you, please consider marking ssidorenkos answer as "accepted", so people see this question has been answered. There should be a button for you under the up/down votes to do that.

Comment: Ok !thanks a lot Clemens! i mark the answer immediatly